ptr on private network ranges
How can i use reverse dns  (ptr)  in a private network for example 192.168.0.x/24 .
Can this be done using dnsmasq or is a complete dns server required for this to work as a forwarder ?

There is no mention of Ubuntu in your question. So I need to ask what does this have to do with Ubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

The underlaying system is a Raspberry Pi running an Arm version of Ubuntu 24.04 Lts, but i guess youre correct in saying that this in not ubuntu specific but more a Linux networking question. The aim is getting it working as lightweigth as possible without using any hypervisors or microservice tech on the Ubuntu os.

As long as almost any question has some relation to Ubuntu it is fine on this site. Please add to the question that you are running in a Ubuntu environment and the version of Ubuntu.

Basic dnsmasq configuration
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
Include custom PTR records
conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.d/ptr_records.conf

ptr-record=1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa,localhost
ptr-record=2.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa,example.com

seems to solve the issue.    will test with that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
